# How to override validation with Rails + Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying override the :message validates_presence_of email and password, but I can not. How to I solve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The source code [shows](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb#L53) another route: you can override some methods to determine whether they are needed:

```
  def password_required?
    !persisted? || !password.nil? || !password_confirmation.nil?
  end

  def email_required?
    true
  end
```

Put those functions in your user model, and change them as needed.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, you should also call `super`, e.g. `def password_required?; guest? ? false : super; end`.

Answer (score 6):

I describe here how to customize your devise validations: http://jessewolgamott.com/blog/2011/12/08/the-one-where-devise-validations-are-customized/

You'll remove :validatable and replace/customize the rest

Comment: Ok, but I did not want remove :validatable, is possible?

Comment: No, not possible. You replace valuations, not customize them in devise